# How to get a transaction list like etherscan?

Tags: etherscan

I have been using etherscan for a couple hours now but it's making me VERY frustrated to say the least, the API is very bad. I'm currently querying all transactions by x address.. This value changes every 10-15 minutes to data from a day old, which is dramatic and ruins my whole application.

Are there any other options than etherscan as I'm getting really frustrated right now. I'm currently using:

```js
const config = {
  url: `https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=${txType}&address=${address}&contractaddress=${contractAddress}&page=1&offset=1000&sort=asc&apikey=` + sample(ETHERSCAN_API_KEYS),
  headers: {
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Expires": "0"
  }
};
let request = await axios(config);
```

To request my data, and I can literally see it change in the browser, I get correct results for about 5 minutes after which both on my code and on my browser it changes back to old data again.

Is there any possibility that this is me or is etherscan just very very bad?

If it's not me please if someone knows and alternative I'm very desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/) and [Infura](https://www.infura.io/) to write small applications and their free plans covered my needs. I think they can be good alternatives for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello** what are you trying to do **exactly** to help ? when saying request data ?

Are you using your **own node endpoint** or a ***public*** **endpoint** url?